# I created an application with electron, but when I run it in win 7 32 bits, a blank tab is shown

Tags: electron

It works in 64 bits but with 32 bits is the problem, the application starts and shows a blank tab, when I press click and move, the content appears and I can drag the content, but the tab is still blank

this is my package.

```
   {
  "name": "iher-lega",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "its app for win7 32bits",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Erick ",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "custom-electron-titlebar": "^3.2.2-hotfix62",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "filesaver": "0.0.13",
    "html-pdf": "^2.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jszip": "^3.4.0",
    "promise-mysql": "^4.1.3",
    "tableexport": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.3.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.erick.schoolS",
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "msi",
          "arch": [
            "ia32"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "icon": "src/logo.ico"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It could be a target platform problem in the packaging process...

Comment: yes it is but I need it for that platform,I will use electron-packager to see if it works

Comment: electron-packager it does not work

Comment: what is your elctron-packager command line